# Protractor test - Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

When I try to launch protractor test using following command, I get below error message.

```
C:\protractor\test>protractor conf.js
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:155
                throw e;
                ^

TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at beforeLaunch (C:protractor\test\conf.js:96:13)
    at C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\util.js:46:49
    at Function.promise (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:682:9)
    at Object.runFilenameOrFn_ (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\util.js:38:16)
    at Object.initFn [as init] (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\launcher.js:104:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\cli.js:226:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
```

I have nodejs and protractor installed correctly. I am not sure why I am getting above error message. I followed [this](https://www.protractortest.org/#/) official protractor test site to run protractor test.

Comment: Can you please post your code in order to get better help?

Comment: it clearly tells you your error is in your conf.js at line 96

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov Yes, it tells there is error but in the IDE I don't see any error and the same code works for others..

Comment: @mAhMoUdDaFeR I can't put all code here its a huge codebase.

Comment: @Chuchoo There is really no way we can help you with this error without the beforeLaunch function. The error is telling you are are trying to use something which has an `undefined` or `null` value so inset some console logs and you might find it.

Comment: could you make a gist with your config?

Comment: How large is that config file? o.O